# Use checkboxes to filter Elements with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im trying to figure out how to filter elements based on JSON data and match it with the elements attribute.

Not sure how to do this with multiple parameters- with one I would do something like this to match them:

```
$('li.grid-item').filter(function (i, e) {
    return productList.indexOf($(this).attr('data-partnumber')) > -1
}).show();
```

Whats the best way to do this?

[Codepen:](https://codepen.io/Jerryskate/pen/bGdbErZ)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box1">Group 1</label>
  <br>
  <input id="box2" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box2">Group 2</label>
    <br>
  <input id="box3" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box3">Group 3</label>
</div>


<ul class="grid">
<li class="grid-item" style="display:none">1<span data-partnumber="MIG455239" style=""></span></li>
<li class="grid-item" style="display:none">2<span data-partnumber="MIG455239" style=""></span></li>
<li class="grid-item" style="display:none">3<span data-partnumber="MIG455239" style=""></span></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var productList= [ 
   { 
      mig:"MIG1812067",
      group:"one",
   },
   { 
      mig:"MIG1812076",
       group:"two",
   },
   { 
      mig:"MIG1812136",
   group:"three","
   }

];
```

Comment: did not understand the role of checkbox here , can you elaborate more on your issue

Comment: Hi @BhushanKawadkar if the mig  varable matches the data-partnumber and the group varable I want to show it when I click the correspendent checkbox.

Comment: I have posted the answer with some correction in your json and html, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make below code usage to show / hide respective groups

1. correct your json array as each json inside array has extra comma, remove it.
2. put group value on each respective checkboxes
3. on click of checkboxes, iterate all checked boxes to get the value and find respective li element
4. show respective li element for checked checkboxes

```js
var productList= [ 
   { 
      mig:"MIG1812067",
      group:"one"
   },
   { 
      mig:"MIG1812076",
       group:"two"
   },
   { 
      mig:"MIG1812136",
   group:"three"
   }

];

$(function(){
   $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
       var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
       $('ul.grid li.grid-item').hide();
       $checkboxes.each(function(){
          var val = $(this).val();
          $.each(productList, function(index, value){
             if(value.group == val) {
               $('ul.grid li.grid-item').filter(function(){
               return $(this).find('span[data-partnumber="' + value.mig + '"]').length ==1; }).show();
             }
          });
       });
   });
});
```

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

/*** basic styles ***/

body { margin: 30px; } 
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
label { font-size: 24px; }
div { 
  width: 175px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
}

/*** custom checkboxes ***/

input[type=checkbox] { display:none; } /* to hide the checkbox itself */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before { content: "\f096"; } /* unchecked icon */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before { letter-spacing: 10px; } /* space between checkbox and label */

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\f046"; } /* checked icon */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { letter-spacing: 5px; } /* allow space for check mark */
.grid-item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 260px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 220px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000000;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #edeef4;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.1s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.14s ease-in;
    transition: text-shadow 0.1s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.14s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.14s ease-in, text-shadow 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.14s ease-in, text-shadow 0.1s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.14s ease-in;
    will-change: transform;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
body {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<div>
  <input id="box1" type="checkbox" value="one"/>
  <label for="box1">Group 1</label>
  <br>
  <input id="box2" type="checkbox" value="two"/>
  <label for="box2">Group 2</label>
    <br>
  <input id="box3" type="checkbox" value="three"/>
  <label for="box3">Group 3</label>
</div>


<ul class="grid">
<li class="grid-item" style="display:none">1<span data-partnumber="MIG1812067" style=""></span></li>

<li class="grid-item" style="display:none">>2<span data-partnumber="MIG1812076" style=""></span></li>
<li class="grid-item" style="display:none">3<span data-partnumber="MIG1812136" style=""></span></li>
</ul>
```